# Undo ESC-keystroke in vim

Tags: vim

I am using vim for quite some time now, but several times per day I accidentally encounter an inconvenience by hitting `ESC` too early.

Assume I am editing the following file:

```
I want to change 'house' in this line.
'house' should stay like this.
This 'house' should become 'home'
The other 'house' should also change.
```

I want to change `house` to `home` in all lines except the second one. (In this simple example it would easy to write a `:s` command and perform the task, but usually the task is more specific and manual replacements are quicker and less error prone.) I navigate to the first occurrence of `house`, press `cw`, type `hone`, and hit `ESC`. After hitting `ESC` I realize that by accident I typed the letter `n` instead of `m`.

1. I could navigate to the next occurrence of `house` and hit `.` to repeat the faulty replacement. In this case I have to fix all `hone`s and replace the `n` by `m` afterwards.
2. I could fix the mistake immediately, but then I can not repeat the same `house`->`home` replacement, since `.` would repeat the `n`->`m` replacement.

All of this would be no problem, if I had spotted the mistake before hitting `ESC`. My question is, if there is a way to undo leaving the insert mode, such that `.` will repeat both actions? Or similarly, is there a way to tell `.` to repeat the last to operations?

(Of course this sounds like recording a macro, but since I end up in this situation by mistake, I have not started a macro recording.)

Comment: You can estimate the probability of this scenario. If you change the word 100 times, how many times you will make the mistake. If it is > 15-20 times, you should really practise your typing skills. Vim doesn't know the latter operation is a correction or a new operation. If you know it is a "mistake",  and you knew you are gonna press `.` to repeat the modification, why not do a double check before you press `esc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, there's no command history of vim in that you could repeat the last two operations.

However, there's a plugin that could help you accomplish that. It's called [the RepeatLast.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4381) to address this exact requirement.  It provides a `2\.` key binding. The cost for using that plugin and how the plugin actually works is that... it actually enables macro recording *all the time*. But if you could live with that, it should deal with this sort of situation pretty fine.